# Can't Get Mongrel_Service Gem to Start Mongrel as a Windows Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, mongrel

I’m more or less a newb to Ruby on Rails, but I’ve been tasked with debuging a Rails app that guy that’s no longer around wrote.  The app is running on a manchine using:

•   Windows XP Professional

•   Apache 2.2

•   Rails 2.3.8

•   mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)

•   mongrel_service (0.3.4 i386-mswin32)

I copied the app from the server and did some debugging on it on my personal machine.  I just setup a Git repository on my personal machine and cloned it back over to the server.  Everything seems to be working great except mongrel_service doesn’t work anymore.  Each time I try to start the service from Windows “Services” tool I get this error:
The MYAPP_Mongrel_As_Service service on Local Computer started and then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the Performance Logs and Alerts service
I tried removing the service with:

```
C:\MyApp>mongrel_rails service::remove --name MYAPP_Mongrel_As_Service
Stopping MYAPP_Mongrel_As_Service if running...
MYAPP_Mongrel_As_Service service removed
```

and reinstalling it with:

```
C:\MyApp>mongrel_rails service::install --name MYAPP_Mongrel_As_Service -c "C:\MyApp" --port 3001 --env
ironment production --address localhost --log "log\mongrel_as_service.log" --pid "tmp\pids\mongrel_a
s_service.pid"
MYAPP_Mongrel_As_Service service created.
```

But no matter how many times I try, or what options I use, I can’t get the service to run.  What’s weird is that I can get mongrel to startup by itself just fine.

```
C:\MyApp>mongrel_rails start -c c:\MyApp --port 3001 --environment production --address localhost --
g "c:\MyApp\log\mongrel_as_service.log" --pid "C:\MyApp\tmp\pids\mongrel_as_service.pid"
** Starting Mongrel listening at localhost:3001
** Starting Rails with production environment...
** Rails loaded.
** Loading any Rails specific GemPlugins
** Signals ready.  INT => stop (no restart).
** Mongrel 1.1.5 available at localhost:3001
** Use CTRL-C to stop.
```

It just won’t work when I try to start it as a service.  I've done a lot of googling on the subject, but I can't find anything to fix the problem.  It's odd that it was working before but now it doesn't.  There must be something wrong with my service::install line because I can't get the original unedited Rails app to work with mongrel_as_service either.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It turns out that the log file for mongrel_service didn't exist on my file.  To fix the problem, I just made a blank text file and renamed it to the name of my log file.  It worked like a charm.  It's odd that mongrel_service doesn't make it's own log file if it can't detected it, but oh well.